# NoSuchFieldError with JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I try to create a object using JNI, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: bar    at
>   jni_test.JNI_Test.createFoo(Native Method)    at
>   jni_test.JNI_Test.main(JNI_Test.java:21)

Here is the code:

```
package jni_test;

class JNI_Test {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public String bar;
    }

    public static native Foo createFoo(String bar);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo foo = createFoo("bar");
        System.out.println(foo.bar);


    }

}
```

the header:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jni_test_JNI_Test */

#ifndef _Included_jni_test_JNI_Test
#define _Included_jni_test_JNI_Test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jni_test_JNI_Test
 * Method:    createFoo
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljni_test/JNI_Test/Foo;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_jni_1test_JNI_1Test_createFoo
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

cpp:

```
#include "jni_test_JNI_Test.h"
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Class:     jni_test_JNI_Test
 * Method:    createFoo
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljni_test/JNI_Test/Foo;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_jni_1test_JNI_1Test_createFoo
  (JNIEnv* env, jclass fooClass, jstring bar) {

    jobject result = env->AllocObject(fooClass);

    jfieldID barField = env->GetFieldID(fooClass, "bar", "Ljava/lang/String;");

    env->SetObjectField(result, barField, bar);

    return result;
}
```

Why is the field bar not found?

Comment: `createFoo` belongs to `JNI_Test`, so the `jclass` it receives is a reference to the `JNI_Test` class, not to `Foo`.

Comment: thanks, that solved it